# Is there a way mo make the objects in Fabric js more precise?

Tags: fabricjs

Is there a way mo make the objects in Fabric js more precise?

I like Fabric js very much.
But there is a problem with the precision of the objects and text.

Some examples.
The graph in Fabric js looks good with small scale.
But when approached the picture looks blurred:

[image]

In some other library if we scale the graph it keeps the precision:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that by "precision" you're referring to resolution of your objects, you're likely just exceeding the resolution of the cache canvas. You can try disabling `objectCaching` on your objects to see if that helps.

`obj.set('objectCaching', false);`

**Update** - The example you've linked to doesn't use canvas, it's constructed out of dom elements like divs that are inherently vector based. Fabric.JS is a canvas library so every object is represented by pixel data and won't look good if you try to scale the element in your browser. Instead, you should use fabric's built in zoom functionality which will redraw the canvas based on your required zoom level.

For help with zooming, see here: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5

Comment: Thanks, I'll try objectCaching. Let me explain what I mean. Try to scale this graph -  http://fabricjs.com/stickman. You will see what I mean with blurring. And then try this - https://cytoscape.org/cytoscape.js-popper/. If you scale it, the lines, figures and text stay precise. I'm not an expert but scaling vs. precision must be somehow connected with SVG.